# Including transformed XML

Tags: include, xml

I need to include a transformed XML document into my LaTeX source. Transformation is specified inside the XML via XSLT. I recently started using LaTeX and I have bib database in XML. However, this XML file contains a lot more information than a `.bib` file can contain (or should contain).

Therefore, it looks like one of these will do the trick:

- Including transformed XML text directly (which will produce well formed `.bib` file)
- Including a program output (which will output well formed `.bib` file)

I have seen options like running application before and obtaining results using `.bat` or makefiles. However, I will consider these as last resort because it will not be portable. Other people receiving my file should change their editor settings to be able to compile it.

Comment: I'm _forbidden_ from telling you that [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net) can handle XML, so you should probably use that instead of LaTeX.

Comment: :) I found a bad solution, but i will keep the question open if there is a way to do it better.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution with the community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin already pointed out, ConTeXt can handle XML.

Another solution would be to use LuaTeX and write a custom parser in Lua or use a library for that purpose. The options are endless. If you write a custom function in Lua it is at least portable to users of LuaTeX and furthermore a very flexible solution.

Comment: There is a LuaTeX variant with an XML parser built in (based on libxml2): https://github.com/pgundlach/LuaTeX/tree/xmlreader

Comment: I have done it with a hack, but next time I will try your method. Looks pretty promising.